# Linking troubles in C

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, linker, ld

I have a *test.c* that is using code from two libraries. One is statically linked (say *libstatic.a*, the other - dynamically (e.g. *libdynamic.so*).

I compiled my c file as follows:

```
gcc -I../inc -c test_subframeip_omap.c -o test_subframeip_omap.o
```

How do I link now the static and dynamic libraries in order to produce the final executable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You generally need something like:

```
gcc -I../inc -c test_subframeip_omap.c -o test_subframeip_omap.o
gcc -L/path/to/libs -l static -ldynamic -o test_subframeip_omap test_subframeip_omap.o
```

The `-L` adds directories to the library search path and `-l` specifies a library to link with. It's also done as part of the *link,* not the *compile.*